# Inkscape pdf_tex file produces a figure with incorrect width

Tags: floats, two-column

As I recently learned, Inkscape has a nice feature that enables the user [to separate figure's lines and shapes from its text](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX#How_to_turn_an_Inkscape_drawing_into_an_editable_LaTeX_document) (axis label etc.). The output is two files, a `pdf` and a `pdf_tex` file.

Consider the following figure, with its horizontal axis label:

[image: Sine function]

Implementing the file in LaTeX, I get the following result:
[image: Misalignment]

As you can see, the plot crosses the column it is placed at (put aside the axes numbers sitting on top of the axes).

The output was generated with the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol} % To write in 2 columns
%% To include figures %%
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx} % physical quantities numbers and units 
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

Lorem ipsum...

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \import{./}{sine.pdf_tex}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve this?

I guess that the question I have fits this SE website, but please inform me if not [perhaps the graphics design website?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

To download the files: [`sine.pdf`](https://easyupload.io/m/rmrfsf) and [`sine.pdf_tex`](https://easyupload.io/m/rmrfsf)

Comment: your code doesn't compile without errors and it wouldn't create a figure 4. Make a real example and test it. And avoid the import package and subfolders in the example, that makes it only difficult to test your document.

Comment: Indeed. Mistake for me. MWE should work now, except for entering enough dummy text to see the effect. And, I would like to hear an amendment to the use of `import`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such graphics can't be arbitrarly scaled. As the size of the font doesn't change the coordinates of inkscape don't fit for all scale factors, also inkscape can't know how large your glyphs are.

So if you want to use inkscape, create the graphics in roughly the size you actually want to use them later.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol} % To write in 2 columns

\begin{document}
\fbox{\input{sine.pdf_tex}}

\def\svgwidth{0.75\columnwidth}
\fbox{\input{sine.pdf_tex}}

\def\svgwidth{0.5\columnwidth}
\fbox{\input{sine.pdf_tex}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I change the size of such label? Should I make a change to the latex commands inside the `pdf_tex` file?

Comment: You can simply type e.g. \tiny before loading the file, this will naturally affect all text.